# Inserting Partitioned Data into External Table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning, external-tables

I needed few clarification regarding inserting data into External Table.

I have created an external parquet table, which is partitioned by week pointing to a hadoop location, after this I have moved the data (a .csv file) to that location.

My doubt is since the table is partitoned by week , even if I just move the file to that directory , hive would not read and I have to use insert command ,compared to say when we have a hive table not partitioned , which will read directly from that hadoop path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider what data is within the CSV. For example, if you partitioned timed data by years, you wouldn't copy a CSV containing several year values into a single partition. You would need to split the Dataset.

> even if I just move the file to that directory , hive would not read and I have to use insert command

Correct. Especially since it's a parquet serde trying to read a CSV.

To clarify, Hive *would read* the CSV if placed in a table that was stored as text.

You need a separate table where you can read text files, then insert into the other, while converting file formats

Comment: So this is not something related to partitioning, am I correct in understanding that we need to always  use insert command to see data in hive after placing the file in hadoop location  ?

Comment: Partitioning is not the only consideration. File type is another, as I  said

Comment: Can you please clarify in which cases Hive External table will directly reflect the data once I place the file in hdfs pointing to the Hive external table ?

Comment: The external table immediately is queryable when data is copied to its location *in the correct format of the table*

Comment: Thanks cricket_007, I had one more question, suppose my data resides in a single .csv file in hdfs and has a column week , as you pointed out I cant directly create a hive partitioned table,so is there any way I can create an external partition table pointing st to above location in one step ?

Comment: You need to create the partitioned table, externally or managed. Doesn't matter... You then `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE` from the non partitioned data. The only other option I know of is to create one csv per partition (filter with some external tool), create the hdfs paths, then copy each file accordingly. Particularly because the DDL does not support `CREATE TABLE x PARTITION(y) LIKE t` https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable